# Trying to remove redundant switch cases

Tags: java, switch-statement, backend

At the moment I am working on a project and I've got some red-flag switches in my code I would like to reduce. My explanation is quite long, please bear with me.

I've a container object. This container has a value of a certain type (bool, int, email...), and I need to be able to switch this type. For example I need to switch a "String"-container to an "Integer"-container if the value is convertable. At first i thought of using Generics but for other reasons i cannot remake the container Object. I need to be able to change it without making a new container. I made a super-class `Supertype` and for every possible value a subclass: `IntType`, `BooleanType` etc. The problem with this approach is that in every subclass there is a method "`canValueConvertToType`(enum corresponding to type)" which has a switch statement that checks for the different types we can use.

Switches are red-flags, I know, and this is a red-flag on fire since every time a new type is introduced I would have to add it to the switch in every single subclass.

My idea was to convert the current value to a String and compare that String to every type in a centralized class, so that if there is a new type i only to add a single comparation in that one place.

Is there a better way to fix this problem?

Edit:

```
<<centralized class>>
public class HulpMethodes {


    public static SuperType createSuperType(Enum type, Object value){
        switch(type){
            case BOOLEAN: return new BoolType((Boolean) value);
            case INTEGER: return new IntType((Integer) value);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static  boolean canValueConvertToType(Enum type, String value){
        switch(type){
            case BOOLEAN: return <<method to check this>>
            case INTEGER: return <<method to check this>>
        }
    }
}
```

In the old version this switch would be there for every subclass.

```
<<Old example of canConvert-Method in IntType>>
@Override
   public boolean canValueConvertToType(Enum type) {
       switch(type){
           case BOOLEAN:
               return false;
           case EMAIL:
               return false;
           case STRING:
               return true;
           case INTEGER:
               return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
```

The way these methods get called will change to.

```
public class Container {

    private SuperType type;

    public Container(Enum type, Object value){
        this.type = HulpMethodes.createSuperType(type,value);
    }

    public void canValueConvertToType(Enum type){
        HulpMethodes.canValueConvertToType(type, this.type.valueToString());
    }


}
```

vs

```
public class Container {



    private SuperType type;

        public Container(Enum type, Object value){
            this.type = HulpMethodes.createSuperType(type,value);
        }

        public void canValueConvertToType(Enum type){
            this.type.canValueConvertToType(type);
        }


    }
```

PS: had to combine code from draft with quickly written idea so I hope I didn't make a naming mistake or something.

Comment: Show us some code. I am too stupid and lazy to visualise this.

Comment: Can you update the code that you are trying to fix?

Comment: i hope this will help you a bit :)